# Performance between "from package import *" and "import package"

Tags: python, performance, python-import

Is there any performance difference between `from package import *` and `import package`?

Answer (score 16):

No, the difference is not a question of performance. In both cases, the entire module must be parsed, and any module-level code will be executed. The only difference is in namespaces: in the first, all the names in the imported module will become names in the current module; in the second, only the package name is defined in the current module.

That said, there's very rarely a good reason to use `from foo import *`. Either import the module, or import specific names from it.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your answer. I think there're also some reasons to use "from package import *" when the package name may be changed. or there is another package with same functions will replace the original one cause the requirement change.

Comment: Performance difference might accumulate from all the attribute lookups `package.foo` when you actually use `package`. Still, if that's an issue,  import specific names or cache looked up names in locals.

Comment: When a package changes name, you can just `import newname as oldname`. If there's a danger of switching packages often, `import package as interfacename` right away.

Comment: Agreed, `from foo import *` should not be used for forward compatibility.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Do you mean like `import spam as sp` and then `cached_method = sp.foo`?